# Why is cv2.resize transposing the requested dimensions?

Tags: python, opencv3.0, opencv

```
            s1 = image.shape  # Image is an opencv2 image (ndarray)
            w,h,d = s1
            image_ = cv2.resize(image, (w*2, h*2), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            s2 = image_.shape
```

In the above, I asked for output to resize to (960,1280), but I get (1280, 960).

What's up with that?

```
  image_ = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

... works as expected. (No points for pointing this out).

[image]

Runnable example:

```
import cv2

def run():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while cap.isOpened():
        success, image = cap.read()  # (480, 640, 3)
        if not success:
            print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
            continue

        s1 = image.shape
        w, h, d = s1
        s2 = (w * 2, h * 2)
        image_ = cv2.resize(image, s2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        s3 = image_.shape
        cv2.imshow('Camera',
                   image_
                   )

        key = cv2.waitKey(5)
        if key & 0xFF == 27:
            break
    cap.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: This is a classic issue when working with images. In everyday vernacular, images sizes are referenced by width, then height (e.g. 1920 x 1080). Matrices are conversely indexed by row (height index) then column (width) so you need to remember to transpose axes. Add to that the fact that most modern tensor image representations put color channels on the first axis, whereas openCV uses the last axis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on OpenCV documentation:

> img.shape returns (Height, Width, Number of Channels)
> where
>
> 1. **Height** represents the number of pixel rows in the image or the number of pixels in > each column of the image array
> 2. **Width** represents the number of pixel columns in the image or the number of pixels in each row of the image array.
> 3. Number of Channels represents the number of components used to represent each pixel.

So resize in `opencv` should be happened like:

```py
import cv2
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_, img = cap.read()
cap.release()
 
print('Original Dimensions : ',img.shape)
 
scale_percent = 60 # percent of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
  
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

And your question regard why `fx=2, fy=2` works as expected, based on [this link](http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.2/html/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#cv.Resize), when no desired size if given, it computes the new dimensions based on `fx` and `fy` to compute the desired dsize:

- FX: Scale factor along the horizontal axis. When it is 0, it is computed as `(double)dsize.width/image.cols`
- FY: Scale factor along the vertical axis. When it is 0, it is computed as `(double)dsize.height/image.rows`

[image: Desired_size_formula]

To wrap up, I guess that's because in `OpenCV` C++ version, they have considered `X` in horizontal direction (columns) and `Y` in vertical direction (rows) and since `CV2` is just a wrapping over `OpenCV-C++` this mismatch happened for considering what is the first dimension and what is the second as we have in `Numpy` arrays.

**Update**
HansHirse comment:

`OpenCV` is a `C++` library with a dedicated `cv::Mat` class representing images. And, for example, for some `cv::Mat` image, `image.size` returns a `cv::Size` object, which has width and height in that order, such that dimension parameters (width, height) in several `OpenCV` functions are consistent to that. The Python API of `OpenCV` uses `NumPy` arrays, which uses row-major order by default, such that for some NumPy array image, `image.shape` will return height and width in that order. It's not an intentional design choice here.

Comment: That the order of width and height in the dim parameter doesn't match shape is coo-coo bananas. Thank you.

Comment: @user48956 No, it's not. OpenCV is a C++ library with a dedicated `cv::Mat` class representing images. And, for example, for some `cv::Mat image`, `image.size` returns a `cv::Size` object, which has width and height in that order, such that dimension parameters (width, height) in several OpenCV functions are consistent to that. The Python API of OpenCV uses NumPy arrays, which uses row-major order by default, such that for some NumPy array image, `image.shape` will return height and width in that order. It's not an intentional design choice here.

Comment: @HansHirse thanks for sharing that. I add this to the answer.